# What are some common cmd line tools used when developing Asp.NET sites

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, command-line

I'm searching for some kind of command line tool that is a "must have" for developing ASP.NET sites.  I'm trying to encourage other web developers to learn the command line and be comfortable with using it.  I'd like Designers to be comfortable at the command line too.  Where and when it's appropriate, of course.

Just so you know: grep isn't one of them, Find in Visual Studio is plenty fast and will accept regex.  svn, not a big deal because of Tortoise and VS plug-ins.  msbuild and csc, obviously wrapped up in VS.

Comment: Why in the world do you want people to become familiar with the command line? And in any case, the only tool you should worry about would be PowerShell.

Comment: I'm not sure there any command line tools specifically for MS web development. There are a few NuGet packages such as [MVC Scaffolding](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/) use PowerShell.

Comment: Why would I want people to become familiar with the command line?  1) Because I don't want to build a GUI for every single tool, 2) I want them to be able to combine them in ways I didn't initially plan for, 3) Some tools will always be command line only during the early phases (especially on windows machines -- I'm thinking here of Git).  

PowerShell -- yes I'd like them to be able to run PowerShell scripts that can take many inputs, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the `aspnet_regiis` utility. Here is a [breakdown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) of some of the commands:

Answer (score 2):

use this MSDN resource [ASP.NET Command-Line Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293881.aspx)

and this one.

[Run ASP.NET Web Application from Command Prompt](http://abhijitjana.net/2011/02/28/run-asp-net-web-application-from-command-prompt/)

MSDN is big resource of microsoft technologies... 
hope you will get that you are expecting..

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following commands during ASP.NET development:

1. `iisreset` - to restart IIS server
2. `inetmgr` - to open IIS server management window
3. `eventvwr` - no so often to use command, to open Event Viewer
4. `iisreset /status` - to check the status of the IIS services

Also you may find some IIS built-in commands here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525006(v=vs.90).aspx

Configuration of IIS via command line: http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Configuring-IIS-7-command-line-Appcmdexe-Part1.html